# Grafana: want to get Organization name into home dashboard

Tags: javascript, grafana

in Grafana (I have 4.0.1) there is possibility to create more organizations. When I switch among them, I always get home dashborard (I think it is loaded from this file "/usr/share/grafana/public/dashboards/home.json" there is on web browser nice Title "Home Dashboard" comming from that file above defined in HTML as

```
<div class="text-center dashboard-header">
  <span>Home Dashboard</span>
</div>
```

and I want to modify it so that it will show Organization name in from of Home dashboard" e.g.

```
  <div class="text-center dashboard-header">
     <span> $orgName Home Dashboard</span>
  </div>
```

$orgName would be a variable which can be get by javascript somehow.

the url for getting thiss Orgname is "/api/org" which return json
    {"id":4,"name":"Base-medium","address":     {"address1":"","address2":"","city":"","zipCode":"","state":"","country":""}}

at the end it would look like

```
<span> Base-medium Home Dashboeard </span>
```

I have no clue how to write javascript but google search showed me it is possible :). I would appreciate a help with this. I assume I would need to modify this /usr/share/grafana/public/dashboards/home.json file to get work for each Organization switch-over. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can change Home dashboard on org or user level (on org or profile page). Just need to star it first.